# How to fix : "FActorSpawnParameters is not defined" error in C++ in UE4?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm following a tutorial to make a game with UE4 and C++ and a error appear when I type the following line

FActorSpawnParameters params;

It says that the identifier FActorSpawnParameters is not defined.

I've tried to modify some of my code but it didn't change...
So I replace all the things in order.

```cpp
void AUltimatePawn::Shoot()
{
    if (BulletClass)
    {
        FActorSpawnParameters params;
        params.SpawnCollisionHandlingOverride = ESpawnActorCollisionHandlingMethod::AlwaysSpawn;
        params.bNoFail = true;
        params.Owner = this;
        params.Instigator = this;

        FTransform BulletSpawnTransform;
        BulletSpawnTransform.SetLocation(GetActorForwardVector() * 500.f + GetActorLocation());
        BulletSpawnTransform.SetRotation(GetActorRotation().Quaternion());
        BulletSpawnTransform.SetScale3D(FVector(1.f));

        GetWorld()->SpawnActor<ABullet>(BulletClass, BulletSpawnTransform, params);
    }

}
```

I just want you to tell me how to fix this error,
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you include `Runtime/Engine/Classes/Engine/World.h`.

I extracted this information from the [official API reference](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/FActorSpawnParameters/index.html).